# Why wxframe isn't raised from a function called with global gtk binder?

Tags: window, wxpython, raise, wnck

Ok, why this simple app dosn't work.
I've spent one day investigating this and got nothing.

```
import wx, os
import gtk
import keybinder

class FrameWithHotKey(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        keybinder.bind("<Ctrl>period", self.toggle_shown)

    def toggle_shown(self):
        # windowNow id
        if self.IsShown():
            self.Hide()
        else:
            self.Show()
            self.Raise()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = FrameWithHotKey(None)
    app.MainLoop()
```

I don't know why, but sometimes (especially when I raise apps by clicking on them on panel) raising dosen't work and I got flash icon instead of raised window.

**UPDATE**

Ok, i return to the topic and notice these..

1. above example works for me.. strange
2. i isolated strange behaviour which below code shows.. it's something related with wnck lib. So if my app window is deactivated by open new window (left click on window - test1) then raise works perfect, but if other window (replace 'opera' with any of Yours) is activated with wnck(by right click - test2) then actvation fails

   import logging
   import subprocess
   import time
   import wnck
   import wx

   logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

   class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

   ```
   def __init__(self, parent, title=''):
       wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title)
       self.Centre()
       self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.test1)
       self.Bind(wx.EVT_RIGHT_DOWN, self.raise_window)

   def test1(self, evt):
       logging.debug('losing..')
       subprocess.Popen(['xterm'])
       time.sleep(1)
       self.Raise()
       logging.debug('lost')

   def lose_focus_by_wnck(self):
       screen = wnck.screen_get_default()

       import gtk
       while gtk.events_pending():
           gtk.main_iteration(False)

       wins = screen.get_windows()
       logging.debug('wins: {0}'.format(wins))
       for win in  wins:
           app_name = win.get_application().get_name()
           logging.debug('app: {0}'.format(app_name))
           if 'opera' in app_name.lower():
               win_id = win.get_xid()
               break
       else:
           win_id = None
       return win_id

   def test2(self, evt):
       logging.debug('losing..')
       win_id = self.lose_focus_by_wnck()
       win = wnck.window_get(win_id)
       TIMESTAMP = 0
       win.activate(TIMESTAMP)
       logging.debug('lost')
       time.sleep(1)
       self.Raise()
       logging.debug('raised')
   ```

   if **name** == '**main**':
       app = wx.PySimpleApp(redirect=False)
       frame = MyFrame(None)
       frame.Show()
       app.MainLoop()

Does anybody understand this behaviour instead of very helpful wtf like i feel? :)

Comment: Works for me on Ubuntu 11.04.  Any chance you're running this in a virtual machine?  If your CTRL key is bound to some system function (like releasing the mouse pointer from the console), the keystroke won't make it to the guest OS.  Try the other CTRL key, or some other key combo and see if it works.

Comment: I'm not using VM. The problem is i've got almost always hit hotkey twice to get this frame active. It's pretty weird. I don't know how to debug it. :(

Answer (score 0):

What is keybinder? Are you using an AcceleratorTable? See http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/12/02/wxpython-keyboard-shortcuts-accelerators/ for more info. I don't think you can mix pyGtk with wxPython.

Comment: [keybinder](http://kaizer.se/wiki/keybinder/)  I think that accelerators only work within app, am I right? I search for something OSwide like global hotkey.

Comment: You're right. Accelerators are only for the app. Otherwise, you need to register your keys with the OS itself or use some kind of specialized application.