# Why isActive doesn't work with keybinder?

Tags: window, wxpython

After [Why wxframe isn't raised from a function called with global gtk binder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398417/why-wxframe-isnt-raised-from-a-function-called-with-global-gtk-binder) i hit another weird behaviour..

Could anyone give me a solution (hint also would be good :) ) for this..?

```
import wx, os
import keybinder

class FrameWithHotKey(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        hotkey = "<Ctrl>period"
        keybinder.bind(hotkey, self.toggle_shown)

    def toggle_shown(self):
        # windowNow id
        if self.IsShown():
            self.Hide()
        else:
            self.Show()
            self.Raise()
        print self.IsActive()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = FrameWithHotKey(None)
    app.MainLoop()
```

If hotkey is pressed isActive always return false. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Some quick googling found em [this wx.PyApp.IsActive() documentation](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.PyApp-class.html#IsActive) stating that this method only returns true if the wx.PyApp in question has focus. Of course, wx.Frame and wx.PyApp are different objects. Unfortunately, wxpython's [wx.TopLevelWindow documentation](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.TopLevelWindow-class.html) does not offer a detailed explanation of `IsActive()`, however the [wxwidget's documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxtoplevelwindow.html#wxtoplevelwindowisactive) seems to suggest that this "focus check" line of reasoning was worth pursuing.

I took a modified version of your code (removed `gtk` and `keybinder` since I don't have them installed. Bound your `toggle_shown` method to `wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN`) and set a break point on `print self.IsActive()` and then manually ran a few lines of debug code. I observed the following behaviour:

> >self.IsActive()
> False
>
> >self.SetFocus()
>
> >self.IsActive()
> True
>
> >self.HasFocus()
> True

It seems to me that just because you're placing your window at the top layer (using `self.Raise()`) doesn't mean you're setting the application as active (i.e. giving it focus).

Of course, this raises the question as to why there are two methods, `IsActive()` and `HasFocus()`, which appear the check the same thing. I don't know the answer to this.

Comment: Thanks for Your effort, but in my version of code (keybinder?) makes it differ.
I add line: self.SetFocus() after self.Raise() and still have always False value from IsActive().